# Database Supporting Update by Function rather than by Value

Tags: database

Desired behavior:

In Clojure's implementation of Agents, to update an Agent, one does NOT send a new value. One sends a function, which is called on the old value, and the return value is set as the new value of the Agent.

This makes certain things easy: for example, if I have a queue, and I have two concurrent threads that both want to append to the queue (and I don't care which order they append), each thread can just fire off a (fn [x] (cons x new_value)) ... and it just works. Whereas, if it was updating by value, I'd have to do a compare and swap of some sort.

Question:

Is there any database that supports this type of updating? For example, I was recently looking at MongoDB. However, MongoDB supports only $inc/$dec, and not arbitrary functions for updating the documents.

Thanks!

PS -- I don't need transactions / ACID / BASE / ... all I really want is a simple document store that supports updating via functions rather than values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB actually supports multiple different modifier operations (full list [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-ModifierOperations)) and while I can see $inc/$dec alone might be limiting, a simple variant of specific example you give of adding to a queue could be handled using $push or $addToSet (depending on whether you wanted duplicates to appear in your queue or not as $addToSet will only add a value if it doesn't already exist).

For more complex cases (supporting compare and swap type of semantics) you can look at [findAndModify command](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command) in MongoDB if you don't find something simple that fits your needs exactly.

Comment: In MongoDB, is there a way to send a modification _function_. The whole point is to avoid compare & swap -- that I send it a function, rather than a value.

Comment: Not arbitrary user defined function, but your statement that it only supports $inc and $dec was incorrect.  As an example, appending to the queue is something that's supported - you don't have to write a function.

Comment: You're right, my statement on only $inc/$dec was incorrect, and as a result, shifts the focus of my question.